# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am working on Maven.As soon as i make new maven project then i set gwt-maven-plugin in archetype then i give artifact id and then i press finish button i come across with error when i install the maven.

```
Exception in thread "html-unit client thread": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/Apache/commons/collections/Transformer
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.process(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:184)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.getClassConfiguration(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:169)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.buildUsageMap(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:79)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.<init>(AbstractJavaScriptConfiguration.java:59)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.<init>(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:560)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:576)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.<init>(JavaScriptEngine.java:141)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.init(WebClient.java:237)
[ERROR]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:211)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.junit.RunStyleHtmlUnit$HtmlUnitThread.run(RunStyleHtmlUnit.java:99)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR]     ... 13 more
```

Comment: can anybody answer me why this error is coming.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778191/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-collections-transformer

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency> i used this dependency but on adding this i <packaging > gives me error

Comment: can you upgrade to 4.x.x version?